# Routing Error in feature testing with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm working on a Project and trying to write some tests for it. At the Moment i'm doing the feature tests.
The Problem: I just can't use **visit**. Doesn't matter where i am using it. I receive the error: **ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [GET] "/"**.

Here is a simple example of the test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.feature "Welcome", type: :feature do
  context 'sign in user and load index' do
    visit new_user_session_path  #didn't worked with "/" nor "/login" either
  end
end
```

May it's a problem with RSpec? I just don't know how to fix it.

I'm really glad if someone would try to help me.

**EDIT:**

The routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  REGEX_NAME = /[^\/]+/

  constraints OperatorSubdomain do

    get '/', to: 'operators#index'

    devise_for :operators, controllers: {
      sessions: 'operators/sessions'
    }, skip: %i[registrations passwords unlocks omniauth_callbacks confirmations]

    authenticate :operator do
      require 'sidekiq/web'
      mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
      Sidekiq::Web.set :sessions, false
      ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
    end
  end

  constraints AppSubdomain do 
    root 'welcome#index'

  scope '/', module: 'welcome' do
    get '/faq', action: :faq
    get '/impressum', action: :imprint
  end

  get '/partners', to: 'companies#my_partners', as: :partners
  delete '/partners', to: 'companies#destroy_partnership'

  devise_scope :user do
    get  '/login' => 'users/sessions#new', as: :new_user_session
    post '/login' => 'users/sessions#create', as: :user_session

    get '/register' => 'users/registrations#new', as: :new_user_registration
    post '/register' => 'users/registrations#create', as: :user_registration

    delete '/logout', to: 'users/sessions#destroy', as: :destroy_user_session

    post '/users/notification_token', to: 'users/sessions#set_login_time', as: :notification_token

    get '/users/invitation', to: 'users#invitation', as: :users_invitation
    post '/users/invitation', to: 'users#complete_invitation'
  end

  scope '/setup', module: :setup do
    get '/', action: :index, as: :setup
    post '/', action: :create
  end

  devise_for :users, controllers: {
      omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks',
      confirmations: 'users/confirmations',
      registrations: 'users/registrations',
      passwords:     'users/passwords'
  }, skip: :session


  scope '/profiles/:name', module: :users, constraints: { name: REGEX_NAME } do
    get '/', action: :show, as: :profile
    put '/', action: :update
  end
```

That's the important part of the routes.rb i think.

Comment: Can you update the question with the `routes.rb`?

Comment: Sure, it's done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `scenario` instead of `context`:

```
RSpec.feature "Welcome", type: :feature do
  scenario 'sign in user and load index' do
    visit new_user_session_path  #didn't worked with "/" nor "/login" either
  end
end
```

**EDIT:**

Looks like you're using subdomains, is it right? If yes, you should take a look https://robots.thoughtbot.com/acceptance-tests-with-subdomains

Comment: Ah, i understand. But i'm not creating something like a blog, i just want to visit the root page. Can i use visit with a subdomain? Or need i to configure it in the _spec_helper_?

Comment: The linked article shows how to test an app using subdomains. I doesn't matter if it is a blog

Comment: Now i got another problem.. i got a variable declared in **application.yml** for **ENV.fetch("my_var")**.
If i run the test, it says, that "my_var" is not defined.

Comment: Failure/Error: require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

TypeError:
  no implicit conversion of Hash into String